# Use promises within service but NOT returning a promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

So I am creating a service which sends a message to the backend to check whether a particular email address is already on the database.

```
userDB.emailExists = function()
{

    var returnVal;

    $http.get('?backend=users&email=myemail%40mydomain.com')
         .success(function(data) { returnVal = data.count ? true : false; })
         .error(function(data) { /* TODO error handling */ });

        returnVal = data.count ? true : false;
    });

    return returnVal;
};
```

Now currently the unit test for this (testing to see whether the function returns `true` or `false`) is failing with `Expected undefined to be truthy.`. I think I get why; as a promise only returns a 'placeholder' so at the time we get to the 'return' statement, `returnVal` has not been set yet.

Only problem is, I don't know how to fix this; I don't want to return the promise as this seems an unnecessary layer of complexity when the result is a simple true or false

Comment: You can'd do that since you are making an async call.... to see how to handle it - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Only problem is, I don't know how to fix this; I don't want to return the promise as this seems an unnecessary layer of complexity when the result is a simple true or false

You *have* to return the promise (or take a callback) - this is simply how coding is done in async i.o in Angular and in browser JavaScript in general. See [this question for the conceptual explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call/16825593#16825593).

Conceptually the complexity you speak of is already there since your function conceptually doesn't return true/false, it performs a network request and returns true/false based on its result.

You should however - return a promise for the `true/false` value and *not* the `$http` request:

```
userDB.emailExists = function() {
    return $http.get('?backend=users&email=myemail%40mydomain.com')
         .then(function(r) { return Boolean(r.data.count); });
};
```